# Where Did The "Resolve" Option Go In Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

In previous versions of Visual Studio, I used to be able to right-click an unresolved class name, choose "Resolve" and then have the choice to add a using statement or fully-qualify the type.

However, that option appears to be missing for me since installing Visual Studio 2015. Anyone know where it went?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I figured it out.

It shows up as a little "Quick Actions" light bulb.

The "Resolve" wording is gone.

Comment: It adds the long name resolution, but is there a way to add a 'using' automatically any more?

Comment: The top option of the "Quick Actions" light bulb lets you choose "using Namespace.SubNamespace" to add it to the top of the file.

Comment: If using the mouse this is now a pain, in that you have to right-click to get the editor context menu, then select the "Quick Actions" option to get _that_ menu, then select the appropriate usings option. In other words, a right click followed by two other clicks (plus significant mouse movement), whereas before it was right-click and select one of the top two items from the menu. A step backwards in my opinion.

Comment: @StevenRands - I agree.

Comment: @StevenRands I also prefer the old menu system. CTRL+. and then enter supposedly has the same effect, which I'm sure I'll learn with time, but the fact that it's HIDDEN is bad :( It's also less reliable (for example, right now I'm not getting any quick actions to resolve anything from the System.Web namespace)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
If you have dragged and dropped your work item to *Done* Column inside `Web Portal` of your TFS, then you can not `check in` your changes with `Work Item` set to resolve.
You have to first move back your `work item` to *In Prgress* column.

---